# Finding closest point by two given points and their function evaluation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given an implicit surface representation of a 3D object, $A$, such that

$$f(\bar p) = 0$$

on the surface where $\bar p=(x_p, y_p, z_p)$ is a point in 3D space. I also have two other points points: $\bar p_1$ and $\bar p_2$, such that $$f(\bar p_1)>0 \qquad and \qquad f(\bar p_2)<0$$.

How can I conveniently find a point $\bar q=(x_q, y_q, z_q)$ that lies on the boundary of $A$ or is as close as we want (some minor value - epsilon) to the boundary using these two points? I.e. I would like to solve $f(\bar q)=0$ given two points on either side of the boundary.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Could you please elaborate some more? For instance, what is $A$? And what is $p_1$ or $p_2$? What exactly do you mean by 'using two points'?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are $p_{1},p_{2}$ points or x-values or what?  What is $A$?

Comment: Sorry --  A is a object represented by the function f(), p1 and p2 are points given as inputs to f()

Comment: Exactly how $A$ is represented by $f$?

Comment: It dosen't really matter, I asked generically but you can think of a sphere function which differenicable function.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that the surface of the object is defined by $f=0$?

Comment: yes, implict representation, and I need to find a way to get that closest point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is continuous and $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then given that you have two points on either side of the boundary, $p_1$  and $p_2$ such that:

$$f(\bar p_1) > 0 \qquad and \qquad f(\bar p_2)<0$$

Then there exists a point $\bar q$ on the line $\bar \ell(t)=\bar p_1\cdot (1-t) + \bar p_2\cdot t$ for $t \in [0,1]$ such that $f(\bar q) = 0$.

I.e. we want to solve: $$g(t) = f(\bar \ell(t)) =f(\bar p_1\cdot (1-t) + \bar p_2\cdot t) = 0$$ for a $t \in [0,1]$.

At this point you can use one of the many univariate [root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) such as [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), or the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) to solve for $t$ and it will give you your sought answer through $\bar q=\bar \ell(t)$.

The choice of algorithm depends on what you know about $f$ and if you have the analytical derivative, how many roots you expect etc. Given that you have a lower and upper bound on $t$ which also brackets the solution you can use some more algorithms that require brackets such as [Ridder's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridders%27_method).